# SQL: total quantity and SUM

Tags: sql, adventureworks

I have a question.

On the AdventureWorks2012 database, I have to write a query using the Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail table and list the total quanity purchased for each product during 2006 and label sum as TotatQtyPurchased.  I also have to group by ProductID.

Here is my work

```
SELECT POD.ProductID SUM(*) TotalQtyPurchased 
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail POD
WHERE Date = '2006' GROUP BY POD.ProductID
```

But I keep getting an error message:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4  Incorrect syntax near '*'.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close because Stack Overflow isn't for finding small typos in code.

Answer (score 1):

You've left out a comma between the first and second fields in the "select" list.

```
SELECT POD.ProductID,
 SUM(*) TotalQtyPurchased 
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail POD 
WHERE Date = '2006' 
GROUP BY POD.ProductID
```